# How to add a checkbox column to existing gridview columns in yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to add a column to gridview but I don't want to list all of columns(because there are some columns as default).
I know that I can add a column by follow:

```
$widget = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'col1',
        'col2',
        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    ]
]);
```

but I don't want to list all default columns and just add a checkbox column. like follow:

```
$widget = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    ]
]);
```

Then it will be displayed at the end of default columns.
How can I do it?

Comment: not clear what you are asking, you **have to specify** the column names that you want to appear in the gridview, even if you want all or few of them only those will be rendered that are listed under `columns` option

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam 'col1' and 'col2' are in my query. for example my query is `select col1,col2 from tbl_test `, if I don't write columns name in column option of gridview, all columns of query will be displayed. I just want to add a checkbox column, because my columns name are dynamically changed, so I can't specify columns name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yii framework does not support this need. We can do this in other ways.

The first: get all your column names and insert the checkbox column before displaying the list

```
$query = DataModel::find()->select('...')->asArray();

$columns = array_keys($query->one()); // if you know that all column names can also be assigned directly without dynamic acquisition
array_unshift(['class' => \yii\grid\CheckboxColumn::class], $columns);

$widget = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
    'dataProvider' => new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]),
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

]);

Second: extend the `yii\grid\GridView::initColumns()` method of the yii framework. e.g:

```
class MyGridView extends \yii\grid\GridView {
    public $expandColumns = [];

    protected function initColumns() {
        parent::initColumns();
        \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge($this->columns, $this->expandColumns);
    }
}

// in view
$widget = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => MyGridView::class,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'expandColumns' => [
        [
            'class' => \yii\grid\CheckboxColumn::class,
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Answer translation from Google Translate, hope to help you.